# How to allow a full regex expression as an input, mongoose node.js express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, find

New to node.js, express, mongoose here.

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a regex expression as a parameter and return the relevant documents

Granted, I know this is considered a terrible idea to allow these sorts of unsensitized inputs.

Despite this being a dangerous thing to do without proper sanitation of inputs and all.

I can can hard code a find with something like this:

`const result = await Model.find( { name : /Dave/ } );`

and it returns the Dave's in my db

but trying to do something like this:

`Postman:   POST localhost:8080/query

myQuery { name: /Dave/ }`

and in my route:
`
var query = reg.body.myQuery

const result = await Model.find ( query ) ;`

I get a
 `"Parameter \"filter\" to find() must be an object, got { name : /Dave/ }"`

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

I  never got around to completing this question.  I did get this to work and here's the route I came up with. I consider this to be rather... sketchy at best. good luck

```
mmField, What field do we want to search for ex, Lastname
mmRegex, What string we want to find in the field ex, Johnson
mmRegexOp, i or nothing

In this method I return mmKey, which is what I use, change that to whatever you use

router.post('/mmRegex', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const map = new Map([[ req.body.mmField , new RegExp(req.body.mmRegex,req.body.mmRegexOp)]]);
        const query = Object.fromEntries(map);
        console.log(" RegEx: ",query);
        const result = await Model.find( query).select('mmKey');
        res.send(result);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("No Key");
        res.status(500).json({ status: "failed", message: error.message })
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't send Regex over JSON. You'll need to convert it to a regex on the server before you execute the query. It looks like right now, based off the error message, the whole JSON post body isn't being decoded as an object, its all coming over a string.

Comment: Is that a matter of pushing query into the RegExp(query) type function?

Comment: What is `req.body.myQuery`. Is it a string, or an object? Based off your error message, it looks like a string, that's the first thing you'd want to fix. You'll want to look into how to parse incoming JSON with express, something like `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: Yeah it is a string. It's a x-www-form-urlencoded item.   myQuery then I've tried to pass the JSON as a string. 
From a quick search looks like I need to:
app.use(bodyParson.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extender: true}));   

Have to do more reading, it kinda doesn't quite make sense yet.

Comment: I  never got around to completing this question.  I did get this to work and here's the route I came up with. I consider this to be rather... sketchy at best. good luck